# Ansible Cron backup location

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to modify the backup file location when you have backup activated on cron?

```yaml
  - name: cronjob Test
    cron:
      name: Test
      user: root
      minute: "*/1"
      job: "/SomeFile"
      cron_file: /etc/cron.d/Test
      backup: yes
```

Currently the backup is in `/tmp/` and I would like it to be `/etc/cron.d/Test.{timestamp}`.

Comment: Via a parameter of the module, it seems like the answer is no: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/e33e7233d0397528733756aa6cf9f14240d586a1/lib/ansible/modules/cron.py#L664

Comment: Also, there is a related comment by _bcoca_ in this issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16305#issuecomment-226232125

Comment: Thank you guys! I'll do as Zetounator suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html#parameter-backup):

> Param: **backup**
> type: **boolean**
> Description: If set, create a backup of the crontab before it is modified. The location of the backup is returned in the `backup_file` variable by this module.

From there, basically:

```yaml
- name: cronjob Test
  ansible.builtin.cron:
    name: Test
    user: root
    minute: "*/1"
    job: "/SomeFile"
    cron_file: /etc/cron.d/Test
    backup: yes
  register: mkcron

- name: move backup file
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    remote_src: yes
    src: "{{ mkcron.backup_file }}"
    dest: /path/to/my/backup

- name: remove original file
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ mkcron.backup_file }}"
    state: absent
```

If you really find two tasks is too much, your can reduce to one by using a simple `mv` instruction in a `command` task. But I really don't think the very little overhead justifies falling into bad practice here.

Note: you'll probably have to harden this code so that it does not fail trying to move a non existing file on first cron creation with condition and defaults. But I'll let you do that exercise.